# Adding rows to grid in extjs

Tags: javascript, grid, extjs3

So what I might be doing is a sightly more complicated then just adding row to an already existing grid created in ExtJS 3.4 through external javascript. So far I am out of options and out of help.... so any new ideas would be greatly appreciated...

What I do have so far is

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['fullname', 'first'],
    idIndex: 0 // id for each record will be the first element
});

// create a Record constructor:
var rt = Ext.data.Record.create([
    {name: 'fullname'},
    {name: 'first'}
]);

var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    // explicitly create reader
    reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader(
        {
            idIndex: 0  // id for each record will be the first element
        },
        rt // recordType
    )
});

var myData = [
    [1, 'Fred Flintstone', 'Fred'],  // note that id for the record is the first element
    [2, 'Barney Rubble', 'Barney']
];
myStore.loadData(myData);

var defaultData = {
    fullname: 'Full Name',
    first: 'First Name'
};
var recId = 100; // provide unique id for the record
var r = new myStore.recordType(defaultData, ++recId); // create new record
myStore.insert(0, r); // insert a new record into the store (also see add)
```

Now this is good enough if the grid is in the current page... What is making my life crazy is getting the Store values from parent window(window.opener), I have tried accessing Ext object through

```
Ext.getCmp(window.opener.document.getElementById(window.opener.document.getElementByID('MyRecord'))).getStore();
```

or

```
window.opener.Ext.getCmp(getElementById('MyRecord')).getStore();
```

or

```
window.opener.Ext.getCmp('MyRecord').getStore();
```

Nothing seems to work... Please Help!

Comment: Cross frame (cross window) scripting can be very tricky and it may also be browser dependent. Do you really have to use another *window*? Cannot you use Ext.Window instead?

Comment: Thanks, will try that and let you know!

Comment: Sorry doesn't work ... so just to handle the situation bit differently... I know stores are independent of component... so is there a way to find the store for particular grid name ??